# I can't get the NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, isnull

I'm trying to get all the names that have a total amount of zero (or NULL in this case) but my query doesn't respond. I know for a fact that at least one person has a SUM equals to zero (or NULL) this is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT m.name                                 AS nombre,
               DATE(MIN(m.created_at))                AS fecharegistro,
               SUM(p.amount)                          AS Total,
               u.email                                AS Mail,
               CONCAT(u.first_name, " ", u.last_name) AS Contacto
        FROM   payment p,
               merchant m,
               user u
        WHERE  p.merchant_id = m.uuid
               AND p.user_id = u.uuid
        GROUP  BY m.name) AS inner_table
WHERE  Total IS NULL
```

Comment: your inner query just does not return any result...

Comment: Zero is not NULL (thank goodness).  Unless you sum over an empty set (zero rows), you won't get a NULL response; SUM (indeed, all the aggregates) ignore NULL values (though COUNT does it a bit differently from the other aggregates — it never returns NULL).